# Inclusion of Tori induces surjection of character groups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, toric-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field. Let $T, T'$ be algebraic Tori in the classical sense, meaning $T \cong \mathbb{A}_k^n \setminus V(X_1 \cdots  X_n)$, $T' \cong \mathbb{A}_k^{n'} \setminus V(X_1 \cdots X_{n'})$. Let $M$ and $M'$ denote the associated character groups.

Now, let $i: T \to T'$ be an inclusion of tori, meaning that it is a morphism of varieties and a group homomorphism and injective. It induces a group homomorphism $\hat{i}: M' \to M$ via $\chi^{m'} \mapsto \chi^{m'} \circ i$.

**Question**: Is it in general true that $\hat{i}$ is surjective?

This question arose while studying Proposition $1.1.8$ in "Toric Varieties" from Cox, Little and Schenck. In fact I don't have an idea why it should be true, but it seems to me that they use this fact.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is true, but I have too little time for anything but a reference right now: Tauvel & Yu, *Lie algebras and algebraic groups*, 22.5.4 (iii) is a slightly more general statement for diagonalizable algebraic groups. Any torus is diagonalizable, of course.